# Is Leibniz integral rule (basic form) allowed in this (physics) improper integral? Why?

Tags: improper-integrals, vector-analysis, physics

Electric potential at a point inside the charge distribution is:

$\displaystyle \psi (\mathbf{r})=\lim\limits_{\delta \to 0} \int_{V'-\delta}
\dfrac{\rho (\mathbf{r'})}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'}|} dV'$

where:

$\delta$ is a small volume around point $\mathbf{r}=\mathbf{r'}$

$\mathbf{r}$ is coordinates of field point

$\mathbf{r'}$ is coordinates of source point

$\rho (\mathbf{r'})$ is the density of charge distribution

Taking the gradient of potential:

$\displaystyle \nabla \psi (\mathbf{r}) =\nabla\  \left[   \lim\limits_{\delta \to 0} \int_{V'-\delta} \dfrac{\rho (\mathbf{r'})}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'}|} dV'
\right]  =\lim\limits_{\delta \to 0} \int_{V'-\delta} \rho (\mathbf{r'})\ \nabla
\left(   \dfrac{1}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'}|}  \right) dV'$

In the last step, we have applied Leibniz integral rule (basic form). Is this technique valid for the above improper integral? Why?

> **Edit**

The following passage from the book "[Foundations of Potential Theory page 151](http://library1.org/_ads/48AEFC4C49281110D30CB1A8F1FFE9A9)" says the technique is not valid. But it says the equation $\mathbf{E}=-\nabla \psi$ still holds at points inside source regions $V'$. It also gives a "little" proof of the argument.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

> **Proof:**
>   [image]
>   [image]

**Unfortunately, as a Physics graduate, I am not well versed to understand this little proof that the book offers. Can anybody explain the proof in a way in which a Physics graduate can understand?**

Comment: I see more conceptual subtleties passing the gradient into the limit that passing the gradient into the integral.

Comment: What do you mean? Can't we pass the gradient into the limit?

Comment: You ask why the things are possible. I think it's possible to pass the gradient into the limit, but I see more difficult to explain why this is possible than explain why can we to pass the gradient into the integral (after all, the integral avoids the singularity)

Comment: Are you sure it is possible to pass the gradient into the limit?

Comment: I've seen this maneuver before and it seems to work, but I cannot prove it, sincerely.

Comment: Maybe you want to check [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/249559/is-the-electric-field-of-a-volume-charge-distribution-well-defined/252486#252486) as the more suitable answer for you, even though the other answers are worth reading. It works with the electric field directly, but the argument can be used for the electric potential (without the need to pass the gradient into the integral.